# full_join by date plus one or minus one

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I want to use full_join to join two tables. Below is my pseudo code:

```
join <- full_join(a, b, by = c("a_ID" = "b_ID" , "a_DATE_MONTH" = "b_DATE_MONTH" +1 | "a_DATE_MONTH" = "b_DATE_MONTH" -1 | "a_DATE_MONTH" = "b_DATE_MONTH"))
```

a_DATE_MONTH and b_DATE_MONTH are in date format "%Y-%m".

I want to do full join based on condition that a_DATE_MONTH can be one month prior to b_DATE_MONTH, OR one month after b_DATE_MONTH, OR exactly equal to b_DATE_MONTH. Thank you!

Comment: This isn't an RStudio issue, which is an IDE, so I have removed it from the title. I assume you're using `dplyr`? A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be useful – that means code and data that can be used to demonstrate the solution. If you're not married to `dplyr`, you could do a non-equi join in [tag:data.table].

Comment: I'm only using R Studio, so I changed the title back. The code I showed is just pseudo code to demonstrate logic. Can you please give me a short demo on how to use data.table to do non-equal join?

Comment: a little a_data, b_data goes a long way, `dput(head(a)); dput(head(b))`

Comment: RStudio *isn't* a package, it's an IDE. Your question is completely independent of RStudio. The issue would be the same if you ran your script using `RScript` at the command line. `full_join` isn't a base function and belongs to a package – likely you're using to `dplyr`, but you should confirm. As I say, it's a lot easier to answer your question (e.g., demo [tag:data.table]'s non-equi join) if you provide some data, even if it's just a tiny subset of your data or a [toy dataset](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While SQL allows for (almost) arbitrary conditions in a join statement (such as `a_month = b_month + 1 OR a_month + 1 = b_month`) I have not found dplyr to allow the same flexibility.

The only way I have found to join in `dplyr` on anything other than `a_column = b_column` is to do a more general join and filter afterwards. Hence I recommend you try something like the following:

```r
join <- full_join(a, b, by = c("a_ID" = "b_ID")) %>%
  filter(abs(a_DATE_MONTH - b_DATE_MONTH) <= 1)
```

This approach still produces the same records in your final results.

It perform worse / slower if R does a complete full join before doing any filtering. However, dplyr is designed to use lazy evaluation, which means that (unless you do something unusual) both commands should be evaluated together (as they would be in a more complex SQL join).

Comment: Do you know how to write SQL query code in R to achieve this?

Comment: Two options: (1) the `dbplyr` package lets you access SQL databases as remote dataframes, you can then write R code and it will translate to SQL and execute on the server. However, you still have to use the join-filter approach above. (2) the `DBI` package lets you write your SQL code as a text string in R and then execute that code on the SQL server.